# Create silent install of my c# app

Tags: c#, wix, setup-project

i have a wpf desktop app that I have created an installer for using Installshield Lite.

Part of my setup creates a registry key to be created.  When I attempt to run setup I get a UAC dialog asking my user to give permission to do this (ie creating a reg key).

I read somewhere (but cannot remember where) that WIX installer will get round this.

So I created a WIX installer which just creates a registry key.  Again the UAC dialogue is displayed.

Is this standard behaviour or is there a workaround?

thanks

Comment: You will always need to acknowledge a UAC prompt on a per machine install if the install is not run as administrator or UAC is not turned off on the machine. You may be referring to a wix bootstrapper which will run all the packaged MSIs, and EXEs in an elevated process so you only ever need to accept one UAC prompt.

Comment: @BrianSutherland thanks for clarification so if i can run the msi in admin mode it will only prompt the user once even if i did other 'custom actions?'  thanks for ur time :)

Comment: @BrianSutherland sorry been a long day!  why don't i just try it urrhh :)